# How to generate instance names automatically with Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, oop, instance, activator

Here I added a `Tree` object. How to automatically add more tree instances named tree2, tree3, tree4 and so on?

```
public class Training03
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Tree> treeList = new List<Tree>() { };

        var tree1 = new Tree();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Tree obj;
            obj = (Tree)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Tree));
        }
    }
}

public class Tree
{
    public Tree()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an array for Tree?

Comment: I added the treeList. But how to put the tree strings like tree2 and tree3 together with the Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: Those are variable names, not object names.  So this doesn't make sense.  You created a `List<Tree>`, you might as well use its Add() method.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `Activator.CreateInstance` instead of `new Tree()`; It seems like if you used `new Tree()` the question would be fundamentally the same.

Comment: But how can I choose the instance names then? "tree2", "tree3" and so on.

Comment: @HansPassant This is the problem. How to change variable names (tree2, tree3) into object names?

Comment: Objects do not have a name.  Consider giving the Tree class a Name property.

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't know this. So I create them and set the name like: Tree.Name = "tree2"?